# avoid using protected variable names in defining static pure functions

Tags: functions, warning-messages, arguments

I will provide one example to show what the problem is.

```
Collatz[m_] := 
Collatz[m] = 1 + If[EvenQ[m], Collatz[m/2], Collatz[3 m + 1]];
Collatz[1] := 0;
```

this function works as expected but if I make a new function

```
myfunction[m_] := m
```

this generates and error

```
error: m is protected
```

I tried

```
f[# _] := #
f[4]
```

but the output is

```
f[4]
```

expected output is

```
4
```

I know I can use anonymous pure functions inline like

```
Function[#]&[arg]
```

but what if I want anonymous variable names that do not stay in memory? I want the function to be defined by name but I do not want to create more protected or reserved words inside the function arguments when I am defining the function. is there a way to use # or #_ to define a function without creating more protected variable names? is this possible in mathematica?

Comment: What does evaluating `?m` give you? Also which Mma version and OS are you using?  I don't have any issue with the code in your post.

Comment: Your code works with MMA 12.1 Windows 10. However, you should not use "#" as a variable name: f[x_]=x not f¨#_[:=# and there should not be a space between name and underscore.

Comment: ?m gives me
Global`m

Comment: using MMA 10 win 7
I added a space between # _
f[# _] = #
f[4]
gives me
#1
f[4]

Comment: using MMA 10 win 7
that space does not persist in my mma code only on this site. not sure what happened. I checked it again. it gives the same output either way. it does not change the color of the _ but the # turns pink. it should be green if it parses well.
f[#_] = #
f[4]
gives me
#1
f[4]